# How to store sensitive information that needs to be shared across different users?

Tags: python, django, django-models, security

I have to store some sensitive information in my database using Django.

I have a `Client` model and each client has a bunch of `SocialAccounts` (twitter, fb, etc) with an URL, client and password.

Considering ALL users that belong to the group "Administrator" should be able to see the passwords. What's a safe way to store those passwords in the database?

Comment: Have a look at: https://github.com/felixsan/django-encrypted-fields

Comment: @Brandon make that an answer. It is a good approach

Answer (score 6):

So apparently django-extensions has [two fields for this very purpose](http://pythonhosted.org/django-extensions/field_extensions.html#current-database-model-field-extensions):

> - EncryptedCharField - CharField which transparently encrypts its value as it goes in and out of the database. Encryption is handled by
>     Keyczar. To use this field you must have Keyczar installed, have
>     generated a primary encryption key, and have settings.KEYS_DIR set to
>     the full path of your keys directory.
> - EncryptedTextField - CharField which transparently encrypts its value as it goes in and out of the database. Encryption is handled by
>     Keyczar. To use this field you must have Keyczar installed, have
>     generated a primary encryption key, and have settings.KEYS_DIR set to
>     the full path of your keys directory.

So basically I had to install **(1)** keyczar and its dependencies for python:

```
pip install https://keyczar.googlecode.com/files/python-keyczar-0.71c.tar.gz
pip install pycrypto
pip install pyasn1
```

(if you don't have it yet,... install django-extensions too.)

**(2)** create a directory where you will store your keys and create your keys:

```
mkdir keys
python path/to/keyczart.py create --location='keys' --purpose='crypt' --name='whatever_name'
python path/to/keyczart.py addkey --location='keys' --status='primary'
```

**(3)** Add the directory to your settings.py under ENCRYPTED_FIELD_KEYS_DIR.

and finally **(4)** add the EncryptedCharField or EncrytedTextField to your model:

```
from django_extensions.db.fields.encrypted import EncryptedCharField

class SocialAccount(models.Model):
    platform = models.ForeignKey(SocialPlatformType,
                                 related_name='platforms')
    url = models.URLField('Account url', unique=True,
                          null=True, blank=True)
    password = EncryptedCharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url
```

I hope somebody finds this useful.

Comment: As of Sep 2017 the library `keyczar` does not support Python3. And I've given up to quickly fix its fork for this.

Answer (score 2):

Storing passwords using a reversible encryption is about as safe as plain text. Use OAuth or something similar, or prepare for serious troubles when (not "if" - "when") someone will hack your database.

Comment: I thought OAuth was only to manage your users' registration/login... how do you use it to store information that you actually want to share with your users?

Comment: If what you need is to store sensitive informations in such a way that you can render them in clear (unencrypted) form then oauth won't help indeed. But then there's just no bulletproof solution...

Answer (score 1):

For a relatively simple solution, you can leverage [django-encrypted-fields](https://github.com/felixsan/django-encrypted-fields).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to encrypt the required field with salted hash technique?

```
from hashlib import sha512
salt = "thisissecret"
password = sha512("client password" + salt).hexdigest()
```

You can do the same with the email and other fields as well.
Also, you don't have to keep a static `salt`, lets say that you keep the first name of the user as the `salt` or something else.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: because I want all users to be able to see the unencrypted password. If I somehow tie the salt to some user's information, the next user is not going be able to decipher the pass.. and if I use some static salt in settings.py then someone with access to the source code will be able to decipher it.

Comment: i would do some trick like, create a different user group and use the group name as the salt, then fetch the user group name, if that user is in that particular usergroup then there should be an option to view password(just like in chrome saved password).. its going to be little confusing but that should do the work for you.

Comment: using the usergroup name to encrypt the data is too obvious to guess, isn't it? 